# Group By Row Delimiter

Tags: powerquery

I need to group a table delimited by one row.

Each element of the table have a "STATE" with a "START" and "END".
I need to group by "ID" and "STATE" based on the placemente of "STATE A".

Each "Chunk" must have MIN of "START" and MAX of "END".

[image]

This is desired output.

[image]

Power Query may not be the best tool to solve this issue, I would to hear other tool suggestions!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**You need to post your data as text not images so we don't have to retype things to attempt to help you**

That said, here is some sample code

```
let Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content],
#"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"ID", type text}, {"State", type text}, {"Start", type datetime}, {"End", type datetime}}),
#"Grouped Rows" = Table.Group(#"Changed Type", {"ID"}, {{"data", each 
    Table.AddColumn(
        Table.FillDown(
            Table.AddColumn(
                Table.AddIndexColumn(_,"Index", 0, 1, Int64.Type)
            , "Custom", each if [Index]=0 then [ID]&"0" else if [State]="STATE A" then [ID]&Text.From([Index]) else null)
        ,{"Custom"})
    ,"New State", each if [State]="STATE A" then "STATE A" else "NOT STATE A")
, type table }}),
#"Expanded data" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(#"Grouped Rows", "data", {"Start", "End", "Custom", "New State"}, {"Start", "End", "Custom", "New State"}),
#"Grouped Rows1" = Table.Group(#"Expanded data", {"ID", "New State","Custom"}, {{"Start", each List.Min([Start]), type datetime}, {"End", each List.Max([End]), type datetime}}),
#"Removed Columns" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Grouped Rows1",{"Custom"})
in #"Removed Columns"
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you! Using Index and a custom column as base to create an Unique identifier (something like a composite Key) was awesome!

Re-creating your answer on my own, I came across that Table.Group has a optional argument to localy group by delimiter that might work for me.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powerquery-m/table-group
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powerquery-m/groupkind-type

I think your solution works great but here is an alternative as well (if the information is properly sorted)

Comment: Yes, groupkind would work as well. I was lazy